# How to change FTP password from command line?

Tags: windows, ftp

I am using Windows FTP client to connect to my Linux box. But I dont see any command to change the FTP user password. How can I do this?

Comment: Which FTP daemon are you using?

Comment: More details please - what is the FTP server, are you trying to change the password from inside the ftp client? if so which client? etc..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot change FTP user password, using FTP client, just like you cannot change your e-mail password using Outlook / Thunderbird.

You have to log in to linux server to do that. 
Most common setup is to use standart unix user accounts for FTP. For SQL / LDAP based auth schemas, please refer to manual.

You can try login with SSH (For windows enviroment ( recommend Putty http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). When logged in, just type passwd (enter) into command promt, then enter your current password, then new one.

Another way is to login into server using root user / user with sudo privileges and type
(sudo) passwd [username], and change password then.

Comment: 1) Some FTP servers actually offer proprietary commands to change a password. See [my answer](http://serverfault.com/a/648249/168875). The analogy to e-mail client is not 100% either. 2) Lack of password changing capabilities in one protocol does not imply the same for completely different protocol. 3) Also email client won't typically allow you to execute custom IMAP (or other mail protocol) command. While this is common for an FTP client. What makes it possible for user to take advantage of proprietary commands of FTP server.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a ftp command line client, try this:

```
passwd your_username
```

It should ask for your current password and then ask you to retype the new one twice.

Comment: I am using the windows FTP.. Dont know how to explain it more. I start it by going to command prompt and running ftp. I tried this command but it says invalid command.

Comment: You cannot issue the passwd command while connected via FTP command line, it will fail (Unix).

Comment: No, it won't.  As the other answers in this very old question already noted, you have to telnet/ssh to the linux machine and run the `passwd` command at the command line on the server ( there is no ftp passwd command ); if you do that, it does not know or care whether you also have an active ftp session.

Comment: It worked for me, I have just used the command you provided and it asked me to type the `New Password` thank you @rogeriopvl

Answer (score 2):

Some FTP servers implement proprietary commands to change password. In Windows command-line FTP client, you can execute them using the `QUOTE` command. The same on *nix.

Titan FTP server:

```
QUOTE SITE PSWD "<old_password>" "<new_password>"
```

[WS_FTP server](https://community.progress.com/s/article/Can-users-change-their-own-passwords-remotely):

```
QUOTE CPWD <new_password>
```

Older versions of WS_FTP server used:

```
QUOTE SITE CPWD <new_password>
```

Reference: [Changing account password with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_change_password).

Answer (score 0):

Some FTP sites will allow you to change password.  After you enter the User ID.  Change the password as follows.

At the "Password:" prompt you would put the oldpassword:newpassword:newpassword.

You will not be able to see anything you type so you have to make sure you type it correct.

password:(oldpass):(newpass):(newpass)

This works for one of my clients.  I cannot confirm it works on all FTP clients.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is that you could install webmin / usermin on the FTP server and have the users change their passwords that way via the web browser.
http://www.webmin.com/usermin.html

Usermin is a web-based interface for webmail, password changing, mail filters, fetchmail and much more. It is designed for use by regular non-root users on a Unix system, and limits them to tasks that they would be able to perform if logged in via SSH or at the console. See the standard modules page for a list of all the functions built into Usermin.